# Does a Nepali citizen need a transit visa for Korea?

Tags: transit, transit-visas, layovers, nepali-citizens, korean-air

I am Nepali with Nepali passport. I am a Canadian Permanent Resident, and I have a US tourist visa as well.

My flight details are Vancouver-Seattle-Incheon-Nepal (22-hour transit in Korea ICN). My return flights are Nepal-Incheon-Seattle-Vancouver (10-hour transit in Korea ICN). The segments from Vancouver to Seattle, and Seattle to Incheon (and vice versa) are on Delta Airlines. The segments from Incheon to Nepal and vice versa are on Korean Airlines.

My questions are: Do I need a visa if I am not leaving the airport in Korea? Will I be able to collect my luggage at the final destination?

Comment: Similar limbo here. Did you find the answer yet?

Answer (score 4):

Korea doesn't require (or issue) airside transit visas. And since you're flying with two full-service airlines that are in the same alliance, your luggage will be checked in all the way, regardless of whether you have one or two tickets.